# Regex match all character except character start with @

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regexp-replace

Example: "this is the @example te@s5t @abc17$ ++ 123"

Will match: "this is the te ++ 123"

Comment: What regex engine/programming language are you using?

Comment: Does this doe what you want? `(?<=\s|^)(?<!@)[^\s@]+` https://regex101.com/r/hPZCXZ/1

Comment: The simplest is probably to match: `@\w+` and replace with an empty string.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex to match the things you don't want, and then replace any matches with an empty string:

```
\s*@\S*
```

The regex matches an optional number of spaces, followed by an `@`, then some number of non-space characters. For your sample data, this will give `this is the te ++ 123` as the output.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jbAWMN/1)

Note the reason to remove spaces at the beginning (if the `@` starts a word) is so that when a whole word is removed (e.g. `@example` in your sample data) you don't get left with two spaces next to each other in the output string.